# Not showing already subscribed to programs

Tags: php

So I have this code:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta';
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$Sdoubledata = array($retrieved_data);
foreach($Sdoubledata as $Sdoubledata) {
// Het stuk code hieronder haalt de programma's op uit de database waar de gebruiker al op geabonneerd is.
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE user_id={$current_user_id} AND meta_key='programma';");
}
echo "<br>";
?>
<!-- Dit stuk code laat de programma's zien waar de radiostation al op geabonneerd is. -->
<br>
<p>De programma's waarop u geabonneerd bent:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programmatest_action', 'set_programmatest' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programmatest" type="submit" id="button" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?>">Abonnement opzeggen</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } 
        ?>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    // Verifieer nonce en sla de data op als de user is ingelogd.
    // Nonce docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/
    if (isset( $_POST['programmatest'] ) && isset( $_POST['set_programmatest'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['set_programmatest'], 'set_programmatest_action' )) {

      $Data = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'programmatest', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
      $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( $current_user_id && ! empty( $Data ) ) {
            delete_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'programma', $Data );
            echo "Uw abonnement op" . ' ' . $Data. ' ' ."is opgezegd.";
            //Refresh de pagina
            ?>

            <?php
                $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
                $sec = "2";
                ?>
                <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <?php
                        echo ' ' . "U wordt doorverwezen naar de Homepagina";
                    ?>
                    </body>
                </html>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
             ?>


<?php
global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'programma';
    // Dit haalt de data op uit de database

    $NSdoubledata = array("uitwerkingen", "GoudvanOud");
    foreach($NSdoubledata as $NSdoubledata) {
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM {$table_name}" );
    if(in_array($NSdoubledata)) {
        echo "Hij doet het!";
    } else {
        echo "Nee, toch niet.";
    }
    }

    echo "<br>";

?>
<!--De code hier laat de data die opgehaald is zien en laat de programma's zien waar de radiostation op kan abonneren-->
<br>
<p>Programma's waarop u kunt abonneren:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    // Verifieer nonce en sla de data op als de user is ingelogd.
    // Nonce docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/
    if (isset( $_POST['programma'] ) && isset( $_POST['set_programma'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['set_programma'], 'set_programma_action' )) {

      $data = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'programma', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
      $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( $current_user_id && ! empty( $data ) ) {
            //voeg de huidige user_id en data toe in de rij met meta_key programma
            add_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'programma', $data );
            echo "U bent geabonneerd op". ' ' . $data;
        }
    }
?>
```

What I tried:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$skip = array($retrieved_data);
if(in_array($retrieved_data, $skip)) {

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'programma';
    // This retrieves the data from the database
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM {$table_name}" );
    echo "<br>";

}

?>
```

The code allows the user to subscribe to a program and to cancel his/her subscription. However, when the user has subscribed to a program, the programs he/she has already subscribed to is still shown at the place where it allows users to subscribe to a program.

Example:

[image]

As you can see, in the first part, the user can see to which programs he or she is already subscribed to. In the second part, the user can choose which program he or she can subscribe to. Since the user is already subscribed to "uitwerkingen" he should not be able to see it as an option to suscribe to. I have already looked on Stack Overflow for a solution but I cannot find any.

How can I fix this?

My database structure:

usermeta table:

[image]

programma table:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

This is the first loop over the data I do to show all the subscribed to programs.

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta';
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
//I made an array containing all the subscribed to programs
$Sdoubledata = array("uitwerkingen", "GoudvanOud");
foreach($Sdoubledata as $Sdoubledata) {
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE user_id={$current_user_id} AND meta_key='programma';");
if(in_array("uitwerkingen", "GoudvanOud")) {
    continue;
}
}
echo "<br>";
?>
```

And this is the second loop:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'programma';
    // I made an array containing all the programs a user can subscribe to.
    $NSdoubledata = array("uitwerkingen", "GoudvanOud");
    // I made a foreach which contains the result of the query
    foreach($NSdoubledata as $NSdoubledata) {
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM {$table_name}" );
    // I want to output the programs as you told me.
    echo ($NSdoubledata);
    }

    echo "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: If would probably just put the IDs of the already subscribed programs into an array, while you loop over the result of that first query. Then in the second loop over all available programs, you can simply use `in_array`  to check if the current program is one you output above as a subscribed one already, and skip outputting it now.

Comment: The programs are saved in the usermeta table. It has a umeta_id. But that id takes along the metakey, user_id and meta_value with it. @CBroe

Comment: The `meta_value` corresponds to the `ID_prog` value from the program table, I suppose? Well then you have everything you need.

Comment: (The only thing you are doing _fundamentally_ wrong here IMHO, would be that you created your own table for the programs to begin with. In a WordPress system, these should rather be implemented as a Custom Post Type.)

Comment: id_prog is in another table. Not the usermeta table. @CBroe. Could u give me a example of what the code looks like in an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: But the usermeta table needs to contain _some_ value for that key, to represent that connection between a user and a subscribed program - and presumably that _is_ the ID from the programma table, is it not? What else would it be? And no, I am not going to write “examples” for minor stuff like this upfront, I want you see have a try first.

Comment: No, in there is a ````meta_key```` value called programma. All programs along with their users are saved with this ````meta_key```` value. @CBroe

Comment: And _what_ are you saving under this meta key?

Comment: Programma, please check my question edit. Last picture @CBroe.

Comment: Okay, so you are storing the program _name_, apparently. How do you store this when the user subscribes to _several_ programs? (And please use your _words_ when answering, instead of pointing at images all the time.)

Comment: No its not the programs that are saved. It is simply a word to identify what kind of things are saved in that row. That is why it is called a metakey. It is automatically made by Wordpress. @CBroe

Comment: You are not making much sense here. I know what WP meta data is, and how it gets stored. What you _put into_ any custom meta data fields is completely up to you however. So if you made a connection between users and programs via the user meta data - then you must have stored _something_ that identifies a particular program, into the user meta data, under that key. And my question how you store _more than one_ subscribed program per user, is also still unanswered.

Comment: The user id along with the new program it is subscribed to is stored in a new row in the table with metakey programma. That is how more than one subscribed proogram is stored per user. @CBroe

Comment: Well then what I said in the very first comment should still apply, just change “ID” for “name” then in that logic.

Comment: "If would probably just put the IDs of the already subscribed programs into an array, ". That would require me to put hunreds of id's in an array and add id's as well. That is impossible. I also do not have a variable that contains these id's. I do not know how I could make one. @CBroe

Comment: No one said anything about a _static_ array … I was talking about an array you fill _dynamically_, while you are looping over the data the first time. (And that you should switch “id” for “name” then, if that is what you used as the identifiying value, I just said in the previous comment.)

Comment: @CBroe, yeah but I do not have anything called ID.

Comment: And that’s why I am saying, for the THIRD time now, use the _name_ instead of _id_ then …

Comment: Ok, I tried to apply what you said. Do you know where I go wrong? I added what I tried in my new question edit. @CBroe

Comment: _“Do you know where I go wrong?”_ - IMHO in too many places simultaneously, for it to even make sense to continue this discussion. ($retrieved_data does not appear to be set the first time you try to access it; how you are tying to use in_array makes really no sense - you _created_ $skip as an array containing $retrieved_data, and now you want to check if $retrieved_data is contained in $skip; etc.)

Comment: Oke @CBroe. If you mind giving this one last try. I did what you told me to do in the first answer. I also used a ````foreach````. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong now. It stil displays double the data.

Comment: I did not mean that you should throw away what you already had completely, just modify it a bit. _In_ your first loop over the data, to output the already subscribed programs, put the name of each program you encounter, into an array. In the second loop, that outputs the programs the user can (still) subscribe to - check if the name of the program is in that array already. If it is, simply _skip it_ now (`continue`).

Comment: The main problem I have right now that the ````if(in_array($NSdoubledata))```` is not working. It just goes to the else-statement. @CBroe

Comment: I did read it yesterday. I also tried putting the variable in there as a parameter. It still will not echo only one of the requested values. @CBroe

Comment: It is close to impossible to tell what you actually tried now, with all the edits and additional code snippets shown elsewhere, out of context. And what I see, appears to have rather little to do, with what I actually described. _Last_ attempt from my side: Show what you tried, in context of the full script. (Add that as a new edit at the bottom of the question, please, so that this does not completely lose question history & context.)

Comment: @CBroe. I added the new added in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a simple SQL change will resolve this for you.

```
SELECT Anaam FROM programma
WHERE ID_prog NOT IN 
      (SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE user_id={$current_user_id})
```

So if you change this in your line that currently reads

```
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM {$table_name}" );
```

This should then look more like

```
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM programma WHERE ID_prog NOT IN (SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE user_id={$current_user_id})" );
```

This should then only produce the lists of programs that the user is not already subscribed to.

Good luck!